# Problemas con mi contador de eventos en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

estoy tratando de hacer un query que cuente los numeros de eventos conforme esten en el dia, por ejemplo:

[image: Cuento el numero de eventos que existen por dia y los que se cruzan entre ellos]

Lo que sucede con mi query es que a la hora de registrar eventos se llega a resetear el contador de los eventos del dia, por ejemplo aqui, el evento de frutas deberia ser el numero 3 pero el contador se resetea y comienza de nuevo en el 1:

[image: El evento de frutas deberia de ser el numero 3 pero el contador se resetea y comienza en 1]

Este es el query que estoy usando:

```
SELECT id_evento AS id, titulo AS title, fecha_inicio AS start, fecha_inicio AS fecha, fecha_fin AS end, hora_inicio, hora_fin, color AS color, activo, counter 
        FROM (
        SELECT id_evento, titulo, fecha_inicio, DATE(fecha_inicio) AS fecha, fecha_fin, hora_inicio, hora_fin, id_estatus, activo,
            @counter := IF (DATE(fecha_inicio) >= @prev_fecha_inicio AND DATE(fecha_inicio) <= @prev_fecha_fin, @counter + 1, 1) counter,
            @prev_fecha_inicio := DATE(fecha_inicio),
            @prev_fecha_fin := DATE(fecha_fin)
        FROM eventos, (SELECT @counter := 0, @prev_fecha_inicio := NULL, @prev_fecha_fin := NULL) init
            ORDER BY DATE(fecha_inicio), id_evento ASC
    ) s
    LEFT JOIN estatus__eventos ON id_estatus = id_estatus_evento
    WHERE activo = 1
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar el por que el contador no sigue contando correctamente, muchas gracias!

Por ultimo les comparto el resultado de mi query al ejecutarlo en HeidiSQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]